# How to put a Variable inside a variable in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

I'm making a bat file which add/load/rename savegame slots, and I had problem with some variables, the first variable is savegame number, the second variable is the name of the savegame, here is the code I've tried:

```
@echo off
set savename2=FortySeven
set nb=2
echo %savename%nb%%
pause
```

The result I have got is `nb%`

Comment: Replace `echo %savename%nb%%` by `call echo %%savename%nb%%%`...

Comment: **-->** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either enable delayed expansion:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "savename2=FortySeven"
Set "nb=2"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Echo !savename%nb%!
Pause
EndLocal
```

Or, use `Call` for that expansion:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "savename2=FortySeven"
Set "nb=2"
Call Echo %%savename%nb%%%
Pause
```

Comment: What about the opposite?
For example i have this:
`set save=connor
echo %save%`
of course it will show `connor` but what if i want it to print `%save%` , is it possible?

Comment: In most circumstances, you'd use `Echo %%save%%`. Please understand that the responders of your previous questions aren't contracted to you for any follow up questions. Also that follow up questions should be written and posted as new questions, with a referring link if required.

Comment: My apologizes sir, i am already new here, and i don't know the rules well, by the way, i want to thank u for ur answere and for your time. But as i've said, im newbie, so i ask u what should i do right now, to put everything in its place if necessairy